# htaccess mod_rewrite rule does not work depending on word choice

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^enviar /index.php?enviar=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^test /index.php?enviar=1 [L]
```

Enviar does not work, and test does work.

Im guessing that using the enviar in both parts of the rule breaks it, but im not sure why. Does anybody know?

Comment: Does it come back with "too many redirects" ?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: What exact URL are you requesting, and what is the _full_ content of your .htaccess rewrite setup?